# Does the Marchenko-Pastur Law imply small singular values when p ~= n?

Tags: random-matrices

I am reading about the Marchenko-Pastur Law ([https://people.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/833/2009f/lec_6_7.pdf](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Evalko/courses/833/2009f/lec_6_7.pdf)) and trying to decipher the main theorem so it is more intituitive.

Would it mean in any case that if $p/n \rightarrow 1$ (or $y$ is close to 1), then the singular values of a matrix $X$ (or the eigenvalues of $XX'$) are more likely to include one that is close to 0?

Comment: Yes, you'll have small singular values in a square matrix, approaching 0 as d grows at a rate of something like 1/d. For rectangular matrix, they'll be bounded away from 0